# Carrierwave uploading file using fog to google cloud storage without making bucket public and control access fine-grained in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, fog, fog-google

Is there a way i can upload files while keeping bucket private and access control uniform?
as i am trying to use carrierwave with fog for this purpose and followed [carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) instructions but i receive this error "Cannot insert legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled." which led me to make my bucket public and control access "fine grained". also there were some solutions to use "SignedURLs" but in that case i have to make url for every individual object.

All i want is to simply upload .pdf or .docx files to google cloud storage without making bucket public.

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/metaware/carrierwave-google-storage ?

Comment: @dbugger Is gcloud's services free? i tries to follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olPk_uHgRyw. but when i implemented last steps where it uses gcloud it asked me to add my-quota-project for biling purposes. so please guide me in this regard